# Draw rectangle on gplot of raster map

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-raster

I am using `rasterVis::gplot()` to plot a raster layer created by the `raster`package.  Plotting the raster alone works fine:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

r1 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
values(r1) <- runif(ncell(r1))

gplot(r1) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill=value))
```

[image]

But when I try to add a rectangle on the plot usng `geom_rect()`, I get an error

```
df <- data.frame(xmin=-50, xmax=50, ymin=-50, ymax=50)
gplot(r1) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill=value)) +
  geom_rect(data=df, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax))
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to the geom_rect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_rect` is expecting to have all the aesthetics declared (explicitly or implicitly) earlier, but there is no `y` in `df`. Use the argument `inherit.aes = FALSE` to turn this behaviour off.

```
gplot(r1) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill=value)) +
  geom_rect(data=df, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), 
    inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Alternatively, use `annotate` to add the rectangle.

```
gplot(r1) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill=value)) +
    with(df, annotate(geom = "rect", xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax))
```